# Cannot 'see' ethernet switch from web browser

Tags: networking, router, switch

I have installed my modem/router as a default gateway with IP `192.168.0.1`, and then attached a multi-port switch to it. My two computers are then attached to the switch.

How can I get to the switch via web browser (to configure it)? If I enter `192.168.0.1`, I directly access the router and the switch is simply passed through.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you are using some sort of Windows environment.
In that case, [win mtr](http://winmtr.net/) might be of use, use it to connect to the router/modem, it should list all in between noded (including the switch).

Perhaps simpler solution would be to connect to the web gui of the modem/router, and check IP's of all devices connected to it. One of them should be the switch.

Note:
Bear in mind, if you are talking about [layer 2 switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch), those do not have any IP address, since only layer 3 of networking stack has IP address.

Answer (score 1):

I was in a similar situation when I outgrew my Airport Extreme gateway and added a Cisco E3000 as a router behind the Extreme.  I think this may help with your issue.

What I did was I logged into the E3000 before connecting it to the gateway and re-numbered it as 192.168.1.2 which was within the addressable range of the 192.168.1.1 device.  I also changed its default setting from gateway to router and turned off DHCP.

Then when I connected it to the gateway device 192.168.1.1 and it came up ready to go.

Hope that helps.